# how to run multiple development cakephp projects on the same cake server

Tags: cakephp-3.0

How can i run multiple development cakephp projects on the same cake server and access them via http://localhost:8765 ?
is that possible ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using another port to second application.

See this example in cake book: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#development-server